# jQuery validator to allow only basic characters

Tags: jquery

I want to allow basic characters `A-Z, a-z,0-9`, and basic special characters ``` ~``!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};'\:"|,./<>? ``` availalbe on a standard english keyboard to be only typed in a text area.
Looking for help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sample:

```
    $('#text_area_id').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+-=\[\]{};'\\:"|,.\/<>?]/g,''))
    });
```